# Determine integer given residues modulo p_n1, p_n2 etc?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Suppose you know an integer is congruent to, say, $a \pmod 2$, $b \pmod 3$, $c \pmod 5$, $d \pmod 7$, $e \pmod {11} $, is there a method to determine the **least** such integer?

There is, of course, one such integer every 2*3*5*7*11 integers.  Note that each modulus is prime.

Thanks
CL

Comment: [Chineseremainder theorem] (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Comment: Great - thanks for the pointer.